# FormulaR1C1 Multiply with variable

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to put a formula into N column and getting a type error.
How it should work:

1. InputBox pops up waiting for me to enter a number, lets say 111
2. Fomula =K2*NuMib value has to be putted inside N2 value and so on

Your help is required. Thank You!

```
Sub multiplyfinal()
    Dim FrmLast As Long
    Dim NuMib As Variant

    NuMib = InputBox("Enter a variable")

    FrmlLast = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("N2:N" & FrmlLast).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-3]" * NuMib
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You were very close! The last line should be:

```
Range("N2:N" & FrmlLast).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-3]*" & NuMib
```